# objective-c : define outlet gui variables shared by several subclasses

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop

I've got base form class and several subclasses which derives from it, each represent a different type of form with its own xib file.

One thing is common for all derived forms and it's a view controller for footer buttons. This means that each derived form should that view in the xib file.

I'd like to bind all of these footer button views from all forms into a single outlet variable on the super class so that they all share common code for initialisation in viewWillAppear method from the base class.

`@property (weak) IBOutlet UIStackView *footerButtonsView;`

Is this even possible ? if not, are there any alternatives for sharing initialisation code for multiple views on different sub-classes ?

The ideal solution I can think is to get an input json from the c'tor represent the form type and the buttons which should be presented on the footer view. First, I'd verify that this view actually exist in this type of view from the super class somehow (how?) and if the verification goes well, I'll start pushing buttons into that view programmatically according to the json data.

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the property line to the super class code exactly as you suggested
2. To the left of the line, note the circle that indicates that this is an outlet. Try to drag this circle with the mouse into the desired UIStackViews in interface builder

You should repeat the 2nd step for each of the views that you would like to connect. Good luck.